# custom styling of django formset using bootstrap

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

the template contains a formset having 9 fields .we want to style it using bootstrap by diividing the formset into 3 rows each where each row contains only 3 fields

template.html

```
 <table class="table">

  {{ contactperson_form.management_form }}

{% for form in contactperson_form.forms %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
 <thead>
      <tr>
         {% for field in form.visible_fields %}                                                                          
              <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
         {% endfor %}
      </tr>
  </thead>
      {% endif %}
  {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
     <tr class="{% cycle row1 row2 %}  formset_row">

        <td>
          {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
            {% if forloop.first %}
            {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                {{ hidden }}
               {% endfor %}
               {% endif %}
             {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
             {{ field }}
        </td>
       {% endfor %}
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.formset_row').formset({
       addText: 'add contact person',
       deleteText: 'remove',
       prefix: 'contactperson_set'
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 3 or 4?

Comment: i am using Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap up `{{ field }}` in bootstrap class, form filed render 3 column in a row

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    {{ field }}
</div>
```

and omit `tr`, `td`. just use bootstrap grid system.

Comment: i have added the formset script below i also want to add contact person and remove button

Comment: add a screenshot how actually current output shows?

Comment: i cannot add the screen shot as my badge is only 4 , the problem i am facing is that the remove button of the formset is not displayed .

Comment: do u place remove button in your html?

Comment: no but the add contact button is rendered automaticatically with placing that